# Command substitution in the context of the current shell

Tags: bash, command-substitution

I made a function that prints something in the terminal in a certain position and I made other function that returns the new position to print.
However, I am not able to get the function to return the right value, it always returns the initial value.

My question is: is there any way to make the code work by passing my function as an argument?

My code below:

```bash
function print_in_specified_position() {
  local X="$1"
  local Y="$2"
  local STRING="$3"
  tput cup "$X" "$Y"
  printf "$STRING"
}

function show_script_options() {
  COLUMS=$(tput cols)
  LINES=$(tput lines)
  export PRINT_X=$(( COLUMS / 2 - 77 ))
  export PRINT_Y=$(( LINES / 2 - 11 ))

  if (( PRINT_X < 0 )); then
    PRINT_X=0
  fi
  if (( PRINT_Y < 0 )); then
    PRINT_Y=0
  fi

  function get_new_line() {
    PRINT_Y=$(( PRINT_Y + 1 ))
    echo $PRINT_Y
  }

  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n →  What do you want to do?\n"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    1 - Option 1"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    2 - Option 2"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    "
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    3 - Option 3"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    4 - Option 4"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    "
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    5 - Option 5"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    "
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    6 - Option 6"
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    "
  print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$(get_new_line)" "\n    q - Quit\n"
}
```

- I tried to call my function individually, and it worked.

**Code:**

```
get_new_line
get_new_line
get_new_line
```

**Output:**

```
14
15
16
```

- I tried to call my function with command substitution, and it not worked.

**Code:**

```
echo "$(get_new_line)"
echo "$(get_new_line)"
echo "$(get_new_line)"
```

**Output:**

```
14
14
14
```

- I also tried `"$get_new_line"` and `"${get_new_line}"`, but both didn't worked.

Comment: Sooo what is your question? No, it is not possible to run command substitution in the current shell. You have to do something else - call the function in current shell before the command, store the current counter in a file, or just refactor your code, etc.

Comment: `get_new_line` is inside `show_script_options`. Should be outside

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry, I ended up not being clear.
My question is: is there any way to make the code work by passing my function as an argument?

Comment: You can for example check if `$2` is a number, if it is, use it, if it's not, execute `$2`. Like `case "$2" in 0-9*) Y=$2; ;; *) $2; Y="$PRINT_Y"; esac`. You can also do `if [[ $2 == "get_new_lines" ]]; then ((++PRINT_Y)); Y=$PRINT_Y; else Y=$2; fi`. You can use `getopt` and have a `--get-new-line` option that does that. Sky the limit. Either way, if going with refactoring, it looks like you need to move functionality of `get_new_line` inside `print_in_specified_position` function.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the suggestions. I wanted to do it that way to keep the code clean and simple. I decided to take another approach:
Changed my function:
`function new_line() {PRINT_Y=$(( PRINT_Y + 1 ))}`
And changed its usage:
`new_line; print_in_specified_position "$PRINT_X" "$PRINT_Y" "TEXT"`

Comment: Great! This is the `call the function in current shell before the command` option. Post it as an answer.